# Tooltip no aparece TOAST UI

Tags: javascript, html5, charts

Estoy haciendo unas gráficas de barra y para esto estoy usando la librería **TOAST UI**. El problema es el siguiente: en la documentación menciona que solo con poner el puntero sobre una barra debe de aparecer el tooltip por defecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al implementar me percato de que no aparece el tooltip

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que uso es el siguiente, cabe mencionar que como framework css estoy usando **Bootstrap v3**:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 divGraficaFiltros" style="display: none;">
  <p>Intervalo de fechas:</p>
  <input id="rango_fecha_contactos_fuente" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" />
  <p>Frecuencia:</p>
  <select id="filtro_contactos_fuente" class="form-control" style="display: none;">
    <option value="0">Diario</option>
    <option value="1">Semanal</option>
    <option value="2">Mensual</option>
    <option value="3">Anual</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 divGrafica">
  <div id="chart-contactos-fuente"></div>
</div>
```

js:

```js
$("#filtro_contactos_fuente").val("1");
$("#filtro_contactos_fuente").change(function () {
  $("#myModalActualizando").modal("show");
  cargarGraficaContactosFuente($(this).val(),
     $("#rango_fecha_contactos_fuente").data("daterangepicker").startDate.format("DD/MM/YYYY"),
     $("#rango_fecha_contactos_fuente").data("daterangepicker").endDate.format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
});
```

```js
let options = OptionGraficaColumn(true, "Creacion_contactos_por_fuente");

let chart = toastui.Chart.columnChart({ el, data, options });
chart.destroy();

chart = toastui.Chart.columnChart({ el, data, options });

function OptionGraficaColumn(dataLabels, filename) {
  return {
    chart: {
      width: "auto",
      height: 250,
    },
    yAxis: {
      width: 0,
    },
    responsive: {
      animation: { duration: 300 },
      rules: [
        {
          condition: function ({ width: w }) {
            return w <= 600;
          },
          options: {
            legend: {
              align: "bottom",
            },
          },
        },
        {
          condition: function ({ width: w }) {
            return w <= 400;
          },
          options: {
            legend: {
              visible: false,
            },
            exportMenu: {
              visible: false,
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    series: {
      selectable: true,
      dataLabels: {
        visible: dataLabels,
        formatter: function (value) {
          //if (value == 0) {
          //    return ``;
          //}
          //else {
          //    return value;
          //}
          return ``;
        },
        anchor: "center",
        stackTotal: {
          visible: true,
          formatter: function (value) {
            return value;
          },
        },
      },
      stack: {
        type: "normal",
        connector: false,
      },
    },
    theme: {
      plot: {
        vertical: {
          lineColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
        },
        horizontal: {
          lineColor: "rgba(231,234,238,1)",
        },
      },
      yAxis: {
        label: {
          fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
          fontSize: 16,
        },
        width: 0,
        color: "#FFFFFF",
      },
      xAxis: {
        label: {
          fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
          fontSize: 16,
        },
      },
      series: {
        colors: ColoresGrafica,
        dataLabels: {
          fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
          fontSize: 16,
          stackTotal: {
            fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
            fontSize: 16,
          },
        },
      },
      tooltip: {
        formatter: (value) => console.log(value),
      },
      legend: {
        label: {
          fontSize: 16,
        },
      },
    },
    legend: {
      visible: true,
    },
    exportMenu: {
      visible: true,
      filename: filename,
    },
  };
}
```

---------------ACTUALIZACION------------------
ya logre que aparecieran los tooltip pero el problema ahora es que aparecen fuera de la misma área en donde debería de estar, para que apareciera le puse un z-index

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]